# How to list all the users in Mean.io?

Tags: mongodb, mean.io

Is there a command to list all the users for Mean.io?  It seems like the `mean-user` command can only add or remove roles for a single user.

I see that the users can be retrieved in the "mean-dev" db's "users" collection.

Is there a way to list the users directly though.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there isn't but it will be trivial to add (we'll do it - we also accept pull requests for the mean-cli ;) )